# Return data from Return.cumulative vs apply.yearly returns differs?

Tags: r, quantmod, performanceanalytics

So my problem is the outptut data from the `Return.cumulative` function differs from the `apply.yearly` to get the same return figures.

Here's the code to reproduce

```
require(quantmod)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)

from <- as.Date("2016-01-01")
to <- as.Date("2017-01-01")

getSymbols("GOOGL", from = from, to = to)

dat <- GOOGL[,6]
returns <- na.omit(ROC(dat,n = 1,"discrete"))

# Cumulative return
cumReturn <- Return.cumulative(returns)

# Apply return
sumReturn <- apply.yearly(returns,sum)

# Print
print(cumReturn)
print(sumReturn)
```

I also get the same differences when trying to get monthly data using the `apply.monthly` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discrete returns should be aggregated across time geometrically (multiplicative). Summing discrete returns gives inaccurate results. `Return.cumulative` uses geometric aggregation by default.

```
R> Return.cumulative(returns)
                  GOOGL.Adjusted
Cumulative Return     0.04346625
R> apply.yearly(returns+1, prod)-1
           GOOGL.Adjusted
2016-12-30     0.04346625
```

See [A Tale of Two Returns](http://www.portfolioprobe.com/2010/10/04/a-tale-of-two-returns/) for a discussion of the differences and relationships between the two return types.

If `returns` contained continuously compounded (log) returns, then your `apply.yearly` call would be correct, and you should set `geometric = FALSE` in the `Return.cumulative` call.

```
R> Return.cumulative(returns, geometric = FALSE)
                  GOOGL.Adjusted
Cumulative Return     0.06251856
R> apply.yearly(returns, sum)
           GOOGL.Adjusted
2016-12-30     0.06251856
```

Comment: And how do you get a time series with the accumulated returns for each day of the year. Basically time series with the data points of the `chart.CumReturns` graph?

Comment: @WarricRitchie: `cumsum` or `cumprod`, depending on the type of returns you're using.

Comment: I have tried that, but I need every data point for the time series used in `chart.CumReturns` not just the cumulative end result, I believe I need a apply function to roll over the returns series? I should probably post this as a new question? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure what you tried, but it wasn't correct because `cumprod` is what you need: `plot(cumprod(returns+1))`.